# How to configure cmake to recompile a target when a non .cpp source file is modified

Tags: c++, cmake, metal

If we look at the minimal example below,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(example)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp test.txt)
```

Once the executable target is built, it will only rebuild if `main.cpp` is modified. If `test.txt` is modified, it wouldn't rebuild because eventhough `test.txt` is included as a source for the executable target, it isn't used to compile the executable. Is there any way that we can configure cmake so that when `test.txt` is modified, it will trigger a rebuild?

The real use case for my application is I have a metal file that is associated with an executable target (e.g. `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp mylib.metal)`) and I want to generate `mylib.metallib` along with the `example` executable when the target is build. I have something like

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND "the command to compile .metal into .metallib")
```

but this `add_custom_command` will only be invoked during the first compilation of the executable target, or whenever `main.cpp` is modified, I want this `add_custom_command` to be invoked also when `mylib.metal` is modified. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to create a custom target and add a custom command to it that will generate your `mylib.metallib`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(custom_file_target VERSION 1.0.0)

add_executable(main main.cpp) # main target

add_custom_target(
    custom
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.metallib
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.metallib
    COMMAND echo your command that will create mylib.metallib
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib.metal
)

add_dependencies(main custom)
```

You can swap `main` and `custom` in the last line depending on what dependency ordering you want (main depends on custom or the other way round).

See also my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626372/8088550

If `mylib.metallib` is actually linkable you can also think about creating an [imported library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#importing-libraries) that depends on your custom target, i.e.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(custom_file_target VERSION 1.0.0)

add_executable(main main.cpp) # main target

add_custom_target(
    custom
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.metallib
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.metallib
    COMMAND echo your command that will create mylib.metallib
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib.metal
)

add_library(mylib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(
    TARGET mylib PROPERTY
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.metallib
)
add_dependencies(mylib custom)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE mylib)
```