# How to configure cmake add_custom_command DEPENDS on a generated file

Tags: c++, cmake

Please see below minimal example:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(sample)

add_executable(create_test1_test2 create_test1_test2.cpp)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test1.txt ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test2.txt
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/create_test1_test2
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/create_test1_test2)

add_executable(main main.cpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test1.txt)

add_custom_target(create_test2 DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test2.txt)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test2.txt
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test1.txt
          ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test2.txt
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test1.txt)

add_dependencies(main create_test2)
```

create_test1_test2.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::ofstream test1("test1.txt");
  test1 << "test1" << std::endl;
  test1.close();

  std::ofstream test2("test2.txt");
  test2 << "test2" << std::endl;
  test2.close();

  return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

I have a `create_test1_test2` executable that will generate `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`. For productivity purposes, I want to be able to hand edit `test1.txt` in the IDE after it is being generated by `create_test1_test2` and get the corresponding `test2.txt`. I could achieve the same thing by modifying `create_test1_test2.cpp` to recompile and regenerate the equivalent of the hand edited `test1.txt` and the corresponding `test2.txt`, but that would slow down development time quite a bit. I want to know how I can quickly hand edit `test1.txt` and invoke a much lighter weighted pre-compiled executable to generate the corresponding `test2.txt` via `add_custom_command`. The approach I showed in the minimal example is from [How to configure cmake to recompile a target when a non .cpp source file is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628435/how-to-configure-cmake-to-recompile-a-target-when-a-non-cpp-source-file-is-modi), but the approach only worked if `test1.txt` is in the source, it doesn't work if it's an intermediate file generated by an executable, meaning if I hand edit `test1.txt`, `test2.txt` doesn't get refreshed with a new `make main` nor a `make create_test2` call. What should I change in order to make it work for this scenario?

Comment: A note on style... you should almost never use `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. Much better is to use `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`. This accounts for when your project is not the top-level, i.e. it has been in included in another project via `add_subdirectory` or `FetchContent`.